# Want a Sharepoint (WSS 3.0) webpart to display server information

Tags: wss-3.0, web-part

I want a way to display all internals server based information of WSS 3.0 like Hard disk space, RAM usage, etc in form of a Webpart....Is it possible?

-saumil

Comment: Hi All
Do you know of any webparts which displays server-based information?? I think I can create a site for admins, which displays the information in webparts!
I would like to avoid software to be installed on my laptop for server information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this :
http://www.virtual-generations.com/2007/02/15/sharepoint-explorer-for-windows-sharepoint-services-30/

see more here:
http://www.sharepointreviews.com/product-directory/SharePoint-Products/sharepoint-administration/sharepoint-administration_c67_m56/

Hope that helps
Patrick

Comment: Hi, Link is not working!

Comment: http://www.sharepointreviews.com/product-directory/SharePoint-Products/sharepoint-administration/sharepoint-administration_c67_m56/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already know how to write a web part, it is just a matter of querying the information you are interested in using WMI.

[Plenty of examples on Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&&sa=X&ei=d4ZyTN7vDtW6jAejttn7CA&ved=0CBUQvwUoAQ&q=query+windows+system+information+using+WMI&spell=1).

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont know how to write a webpart. I can just download & install then :) Can you please help me for this particular requirement? Thx for help!!

Comment: Once again, Google (or Bing!) is your friend: http://datasprings.com/Resources/ArticlesInformation/Sharepoint2007CustomWebParts.aspx

Comment: Goof Article. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the PerfMon api under the System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter namespace. Through this you can get all the desired information of the server where this web part would be hosted.

Just launch the Performace MMC on your machine (RUN->PerfMon) and look for the right counter name.

I think Sahil Malik has done a cool video aroud the same. Just google it out!

Comment: Oh.. got that for you http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=142